# Perl: What is the meaning of ;\$ inside the arg list of a sub declaration?

Tags: perl

Here is a part of the program generated by s2p, the program that builds a perl script that performs a particular `sed` command.

```
# getsARGV: Read another input line into argument (default: $_).
#           Move on to next input file, and reset EOF flag $isEOF.
sub getsARGV(;\$){
    my $argref = @_ ? shift() : \$_;
    while( $isEOF || ! defined( $$argref = <ARG> ) ){
        close( ARG );
        return 0 unless @ARGV;
        my $file = shift( @ARGV );
        open( ARG, "<$file" )
        || die( "$0: can't open $file for reading ($!)\n" );
        $isEOF = 0;
    }
    1;
}
```

I couldn't find anything that explains this sub signature on perlsub.

The code does work quite well, too.

Comment: Nice question. In particular since I do not have any idea what the answer might be.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [prototype](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes). That particular prototype forces the parser to accept only the usages

```
getsARGV()
```

and

```
getsARGV($SCALAR)
```

and causes them to be compiled as

```
&getsARGV()
```

and

```
&getsARGV(\$SCALAR)
```